# Track Add To HomeScreen Web App in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, progressive-web-apps, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a mobile web app with the Add to Home Screen functionality working well. I am trying to determine how to use Google Analytics to best track the app usage for those who have installed the app to their home screen. There doesn't seem to be a default way to see if an app is in standalone mode in analytics, is there a best practice for Google Analytics to track apps installed on the home screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect if the app is launched in PWA mode. [Refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160283/1057093) on how to do it.
Once you know your app is running in PWA mode, you can use a [different tracking ID](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/integrating-analytics) to track the PWA applications separately or you can use the same tracking ID and use the [traffic source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en) with appropriate value based on your PWA detection.

Comment: I knew about how to detect the PWA, but wasn't clear on what was the Google analytics best practice for tracking it was. The traffic source works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Derived from @Anand's answer I implemented the following:

1. Set up a separate Google Analytics stream for the installed app. This will have its own measurement ID tag
2. Detect which display mode is being used and select the appropriate tag to provide to Google's gtag.js. The assumption is that if the [display-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode) is not  'browser' then it is the home screen version of the app

   ```
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js"></script>
   <script>
     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
     function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
     gtag('js', new Date());
     const measurementId = window.matchMedia('(display-mode: browser)').matches ? 'G-TAG-A' : 'G-TAG-B';
     gtag('config', measurementId);
   </script>
   ```

Note, replace 'G-TAG-A|B' with your two Google Analytics supplied [measurement IDs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9539598#find-G-ID)