# How do I know I am being called from a progresive web app?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I've been following the guidance on [google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#intercept_the_network_request_and_cache_the_response) to create a PWA, but I am interested if there are any conventions to communicate with your data server that you are being called by a PWA. Is the easiest thing to add a parameter to the request i.e.

```
var dataUrl = 'https://query.myapi.com/v1/get?source=pwa';
```

and then check the source parameter? Or should I add to the request header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {  
    // do things here  
    // set a variable to be used when calling something  
    // e.g. call Google Analytics to track standalone use   
}
```

** Assumption made that you are also setting up your app to be added to the users home screen as a shortcut

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the traffic source to Google Analytics indicating its from PWA. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51161074/1057093) on more details.